# How to define array variable in APIM Policy

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, apim

I want to store multiple value in `<set-variable>` policy in APIM.

Is there any option to define array variable or converting string to string[].

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to either serialize array into string, or use JArray, like

```
<set-variable name="array" value="@(new JArray(1, 2, 3))"/>
```

See policy expression doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Comment: That would be even great if you'd have also shared the doc link.